# Inserting bash script variable into regex string

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to run a sed command in a bash script I have which replaces a string between two quotation marks from another file with another string.

The file I'm editing:

```
path="text"
```

Bash script:

```
userPath=$(pwd)
sed -i 's/path=".*"/path="${userPath}"/g' file
```

but after running the script, my file gets edited as this instead of the actual path that gets outputted from the pwd (etc. path="/home/Downloads") command:

```
path="${userPath}"
```

I tried replacing the single quotes on the outside to double quotes, but I got some "unknown option to 's'" error when running the script. Attempting to add extra quotes and escape them like below did not work either.

```
sed -i 's/path=".*"/path="\"${userPath}\""/g' file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems:

1. You are using single-quotes which means the Bash substitutions do not get expanded within the string -- you need to use double-quotes and escape your in-string double-quotes.
2. When your path gets expanded, the character (i.e. `/`) you're using to delimit the substitution expressions collides with it.
3. Your `sed` command seems to not work on my Mac OS X and this may be because it differs between `gsed` and the Mac version.

Here's the corrected expression using `#` as the delimiting character:

```bash
sed -i -e "s#path=\".*\"#path=\"${userPath}\"#g" hello.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your command

- You need double quotes for the variable to expand
- As a result of the double quotes, you would need to escape the double quotes within the command
- The variable contains the forward slash `/` character which will conflict with `sed`s default delimiter.

For your code to work, you would need to change it to;

```
$ sed -Ei.bak "s~path=\".*\"~path=\"${userPath}\"~g" file
```

`-i.bak` will create a backup of the file